# For development purpose only

Tags: google-maps

I'm using google maps on my site mattesnille.se but since the billing project it doesn't appear correctly. I've enabled billing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ9u3.jpg)

I've also checked the website using Google Maps Platform API Checker and it passed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZXTS.jpg)

I'm out of ideas, what else need to be checked?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the same API key as listed on the picture
. Also check if you limited yourself to Quota in the google platform just in case.